# Adding elevation data to existing vector layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm new to qgis and I'm having trouble adding elevation data to my existing vector file.

I currently have two files:

1. a road network with the all attribute information and
2. a vector file with point elevation data.

What I want to do is add an elevation column to the attributes table of my road network.  How do I go about doing this?  I've looked for an answer, but I'm having trouble finding one.

The relative height difference between the start and end point of the line would be the most useful, but the average height would also work.

Comment: The problem description is not clear: What elevation info do you want to store in the road network table? Absolute heights? At start and end point? Relative height difference? Between start and end? Between all points in the line?

Comment: Also bear in mind that a road feature can go over a crest of a hill; in such a case the elevation of the start and end points will miss this.

Comment: Point elevation data is also pretty coarse definition. Do you have points on the road network (like starting/ending points etc.) or just generally points randomly positioned in that area?

Comment: You could get your elevation data into a raster using raster::interpolation (or GDAL_GRID) then use the instructions http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/how-to-get-the-altitude-of-the-vector-shapes-from-dtm-raster-layer